# HTTPS header and full URL path

Tags: https

How do I go about looking at an HTTPS header?

we would look inside the HTTPs traffic and extract the headers and full URL path.

Any thoughts on what it takes to do this?

Comment: In what environment/language/scenario/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

In general your question doesn't make much sense because SSL was designed to be opaque secure transport and prevent peeping into it.

In reality if you control one of the sides of communication you can take some actions. But these actions depend on many details, such as whether you have access to the client or server, what software is used on the server and client side.

Finally, I'd say that this question doesn't look to be programming-related unless you describe your task in more details.

Comment: I am writing an app that does web filtering, I intercept HTTP requests and run them through our ratings system and either pass or block the HTTP request, for instance I block playboy.com and pass cnn.com Now I wish to do the same for HTTPS and pull out the URL from it and rate it.

Comment: @reza this is exactly what HTTPS is intended to prevent and you can't do anything about this.